# Adding user with existing encrypted home

Tags: encryption, home-directory, adduser

My system has separated `/home` partition which is encrypted. I did a fresh install with a new temporary `user`. Now, I want to add old_user back with existing encrypted home. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean "encrypted"? as in hash key? or permissions?

Comment: I mean [EncryptedHome](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about encryption but to add a new user to an existent home, you can easily do it by running `adduser --home [Dir] --shell /bin/bash --uid [number] [username]`

You could try running it to see if it works, make sure `--uid` isn't 1000 or any of the existent user list. Maybe you can read `man adduser` to find out more about encryption for home.

Comment: I had tried that way, of course, but it does not work. All data are encrypted.

Comment: Did you read the part "n the Ubuntu 9.10 setup, the user's encrypted data is located in /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.Private, and the user's configuration data is located in /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs. As such, all of the user's pertinent data is self-contained in /home."? Try accessing the config for the cryptographic hash, and then import it to the new user.